# Error log for Azure cloud service deployments

Tags: azure

I'm getting the following error while trying to publish an Azure cloud service (classic) from Visual Studio:

[image: "Sequence contains no elements"?]

There's so little information in that error that I have no idea what to start fixing. Is there a more detailed log somewhere, and what steps (if any) need to be taken to enable it?

Comment: Can you try to open Server Explorer and connect to the Azure subscription, then list your Cloud Services? That error appears when something broken with that pipeline.

Comment: I can do that. There Publish wizard validates it as well.

Comment: Strange, it works now... I'll get back to this question when it happens again.

Comment: It may be the problem with the Visual Studio or Azure SDK. Sometimes, i am not why or how, and even if that is the cause of the problem, if your credentials are "expired" i saw that issue. Once i tried to refresh the connection using Server Explorer, it started to work.

Comment: Which versions of VS and Azure SDK do you use, by the way?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me that works is to refresh the Azure connection. I use for that the Server Explorer - expand the needed service branch lead to the solution.

The solution can be refresh the credentials as well. It may be connected with the Visual Studio or Azure SDK versions, so it is worth to try to start from reinstalling at least Azure SDK.